# Java Get RGB value of a pixel in Icon

Tags: java, click, icons, rgb

I am writing a MouseListener click event, when I click on a JLabel it will give me the RGB value of the pixel that I clicked.

I can use

`mybufferedImage.getRGB(e.getPoint().x, e.getPoint().y`

However, I am having trouble retrieving the Icon as a BufferedImage.

I KNOW that I can retrieve the Icon and then convert to BufferedImage, but I am wondering if there is an equivalent way of getting the RGB value of the Icon without having to convert to BufferedImage? My main concern is performance, every time I retrieve the RGB value I don't want to have to convert the entire image, especially when I am working with very large images.

Thank you

Comment: Personally, I'd not use a `JLabel` for this and instead use a `BufferedImage` and a custom component to paint it, you'd gain more control and flexibility

Comment: You could also paint the icon to `BufferedImage`, but you might not get the same color model :/

Comment: Maybe consider something more [like this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158550/zoom-box-for-area-around-mouse-location-on-screen/18158845#18158845) or [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139030/java-rgb-value-code-robot-class/16139916#16139916)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Robot.getPixelColor(...)` method to get the pixel color at a given point on the screen.

You will first need to convert the mouse point to a point on the screen using the `SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(...)` method.

> My main concern is performance,

Not really an issue. I mean how fast can you click the mouse?